# Drop shadow animation on ViewPager when pressed

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-animation, material-design

I want my ViewPager to have the same material design animation as a material design themed Button, where when you press it, you see the elevation change and a shadow appear below the button. The effect is shown here in the material design guidelines under the material response video: http://www.google.com/design/spec/animation/responsive-interaction.html#responsive-interaction-user-input.

I believe that for the Button/ImageView this is done with a StateListAnimator, but I cant work out a way to do the same for a ViewPager, which does not seem to have the states which a button has.

I tried using onInterceptTouch and onTouch on a custom ViewPager to listen to when the ViewPager is pressed and released, but not all the MotionEvents get sent though to the ViewPager according to my experiment.

I also tried using a PageTransformer with only limited success.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: How about making your ViewPager items Buttons, then make them clickable, so StateListAnimator now will be applied to your items instead?

Comment: Buttons are not ViewGroups so they cannot have any content in them.

Comment: You can put it inside a FrameLayout or RelativeLayout right? As long as the click event reaches the Button, my guess is that the effect will apply to it.

Comment: `ViewPager`s aren't really meant to do that, but I can think of a few ways to achieve this, but I wouldn't recommend it. I assume you have a horizontal list of items which can be scrolled through and only one can be viewed at a time, but you also want to select/click on those items and perform some action on click? If those items are more than just dumb content then possibly a `ViewPager` is the way to go. Otherwise if the user is just scrolling trough a list of simple selectable items then you are better of with a horizontal `RecyclerView` and possibly a custom `LayoutManager`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to edit your item layout. Add this to the Button/View/ImageView:

```
android:stateListAnimator="@anim/item_elevation"
```

Then add this animation (anim/item_elevation.xml, for example). Assuming your initial elevation is 1dp:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:state_enabled="true"
    android:state_pressed="true">
    <objectAnimator
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
        android:propertyName="translationZ"
        android:valueFrom="1dip"
        android:valueTo="3dip"
        android:valueType="floatType" />
</item>
<item>
    <objectAnimator
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
        android:propertyName="translationZ"
        android:valueFrom="3dip"
        android:valueTo="1dip"
        android:valueType="floatType" />
</item>
```

**NOTE**: if you want to have the ripple effect add:
android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground" (default)
or android:background="?selectableItemBackground" (AppCompat)

Comment: I have tried this but I am trying to add this to a ViewPager, which afaik does not have these states, so does not get picked up.

Comment: This does work though when you apply it to a Button/ImageView, just not a ViewPager.